# When commenting before deleting a post, is the comment lost?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments, deleted-posts

Sometimes it is appropriate to delete your own answer or question. That is often because someone explained a problem, and one accepts that the question or answer is not valuable. That is not directly related to down voting - an answer may be well liked, but not actually applicable.

When I agree to delete it based on the comment, I would typically like to reply to the comment - just before deleting the post. This comment I write is associated with that deleted post, and becomes unavailable with it. But that does not mean it is immediately completely lost.

I write that comment not to have it permanently associated with the question or answer, but to reply to the comment that convinced me to delete the post. It is typically to roughly explain my reasoning - or just thanking for the hint by explaining that I learned something from it.

All that is relevant to me is that the recipient (indicated by @) can somehow read the comment - even if it does not become permanent. It could appear in the inbox - and would be visible in part there - truncated to fit the space. Does the notification stay in the inbox even if the associated post is deleted? Can it still be read in full?

Comment: I've run into this issue when I answered a question, and realize later, due to a comment, that I erred.  I proceed to notify via a comment to the commenter, beginning with @commenter'sname, below the question, and then I delete my answer (I usually also leave the same comment below my answer, before deleting it).  Also, if I realize (on my own review of my answer) that I erred and choose to delete it, I notify the asker in a comment below the question with a brief explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does the notification stay in the inbox even if the associated post is deleted?

Yes, it does. This is not a particularly nice example, but it happened to me yesterday on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329026/cx-oracle-databaseerror-dpi-1039-statement-was-already-closed?noredirect=1#comment1073823_329026). When I scroll down in my inbox, I see:

[image]

and when I click on it, I'm led to the comment:

[image]

> Can it still be read in full?

If the recipient can view deleted posts, by [having 10k reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or otherwise (e.g. if they answered the question you deleted), then yes. Otherwise, no. I've checked the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox) as well, and it also only returns the truncated comment text, so I can't see [this comment](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/61703/which-linux-distros-is-best-for-flutter?noredirect=1#comment82282_61703) which is still in my inbox. I simply don't have enough reputation on Software Recommendations.

Comment: What about comments left by a user (by an asker or answerer) to other users who answered or asked (respectively), but have reputation under 10K?  Do those "other users" who have under 10K rep get any notification alerting them to any comment left by the asker/answerer?

Comment: Yes, they get a notification (see the updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

The comment is not lost. It will stay with the post, which shows up for users with more >10k rep (2k on beta sites). If the user who commented to you has enough rep to see deleted posts, they will still be able to see your comment after you delete the post.

Comment: This repeats only part of @Glorfindel's answer.  But I'll ask you, too, to expand:  What about comments left by a user (by an asker or answerer) to other users who answered or asked (respectively), but those other user(s) has/have reputation under 10K?  Do those "other users" who have under 10K rep get any notification alerting them to any comment left by the asker/answerer?

Comment: I don't believe so. I couldn't say for sure, but I believe I have seen it happen before I got the rep necessary to see deleted posts on one site that I woke up to notifications on my phone about responses in my inbox, only to log onto my computer and not see have the notification in my SE inbox.